# How to know at runtime if NSHighResolutionCapable was applied?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, retina-display, retina

How can I know at runtime if NSHighResolutionCapable flag was supplied in info.plist and actually applied or not? `screen:backingScaleFactor()` returns 2 on a HIDPI display even if my app is actually autoscaled, when it should, in fact return 1.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. I tried setting `NSHighResolutionCapable` in `Info.plist` to `false` and got a `backingScaleFactor` of `1`. OS X 10.10.4 & Xcode 6.4.

Comment: I thought that by default (i.e. without an info.plist file) apps are not hi-res capable, so backingScaleFactor() should return 1. Instead it returns 2 but the window is still stretched by default. I guess I don't understand this flag really.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? For the default `backingScaleFactor` & other details, [see this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW3).